# Unable to apply image through css

Tags: css, image, background

I am New to web-design. I have learned it by myself but its very hard for me to understand "CSS". I am trying to build a simple website were I want to insert image using CSS than using img tag but the image doesn't show up.

Its happening only with one image which has transparent background and 300px/300px.

My folder directory:

> index.html
>
> images (folder)
>
> css (folder)

Above are the files I have in my project. And below is my code I have used.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>XYZ</title>    
  <meta  charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <header id="main">
      <h1 ><a href="/" id="logo"></a>XYZ</h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Report bugs</a></li>  
      </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
```

CSS

```css
/** web-page default stylings **/

body {
background-color: #efefef;
line-height: 17px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;    
}

/** content styling **/
#logo {
background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: if your image folder is called "imgaes" and you call it via "images" it'll naturaly not work!

Comment: no i am sorry its a typo. my folder name is images. its working for all other images, i mean when i tried adding to body it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PJgCt/

```
#logo {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: url('http://www.smiley-faces.org/wallpaper/smiley-face-wallpaper-widescreen-001.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;  
}
```

I would recommend making the #logo a div by itself instead of calling it in the a tag.  Also you can use the background-size attribute to fill up the full width/height.  I provided a JS fiddle that should help you.

I hope this helps you, Good Luck!

Comment: it did work thanks a lot. but its weird why it didn't work out with my syntax. whats wrong in it ?

Comment: I'm glad I could help you Mythreya.  Welcome to the site by the way!  Keep posting great questions and showing your code and you'll enjoy the site! Good Luck in your development!

Comment: Thanks matt i appreciate your help but can you also explain me whats wrong with my syntax ?

Comment: Could you give a more specific example?

Comment: so if you look at my html i have used html5 header tag and used h1 inside it because i want to put that text on my logo with css.but i was unable to display image. can you explain me what i have done wrong?. did i do wrong way of coding in html or css or both?

Comment: It's because you didn't have a set width and height. If you have an <a> tag for example it's width and height by default are 0. So there is no space to display the image. Also I told you to set the <a> tag as display: block; because then it will behave as a block level element like a <div> tag suggested by Matt here. He used the background-size: 100%; to make sure the image would fit inside the <div> or <a> tag regardless of it's native size. Hope that helps. +1 for background-size.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a Width and Height to the block element (#logo) for it to display. Otherwise it's an empty container with a background image sitting at width: 0; height: 0; Also adding a display: block; to turn the  tag into a block level element.

Again display block is key for my solution. http://jsfiddle.net/olwez/T5evL/

html.

```
<a href="#" id="logo"></a>
```

css

```
#logo {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: even after i added height and width its not working. i have no idea whats wrong. is there any way i can share the screenshot of it ?